# how to develop and run ejb in netbean6.7?

Tags: java, netbeans, ejb-3.0

I am beginner of studying EJB . I want to test very very small ejb application  in  netbean 6.7. The code are as follows

```
package jeenptbeans;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
public interface NewSessionRemote {
    public String getEchoString(String clientString);

}

package jeenptbeans;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class NewSessionBean implements NewSessionRemote, NewSessionLocal {

 public String getEchoString(String clientString) {
return clientString + " - from session bean";
}
 public String getdisString(String clientString) {
return clientString + " - from session bean";
}
```

So , I created  File-->New Project-->EJB module .And  Right click the project and choose New-->Session bean and add above code.But I run this project, "build successfully"  message is shown.So I want to test this bean with client application. So I made "Enterprise Application Client" app and add ejb as follows.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import jeenptbeans.NewSessionRemote;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import jeenptbeans.NewSessionBean;

public class Main {
    @EJB
    private static NewSessionRemote newSessionBean;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
              InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
             newSessionBean = (NewSessionBean)ctx.lookup(NewSessionBean.class.getName());

            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            String returnedString = newSessionBean.getEchoString(args[i]);
            System.out.println("sent string: " + args[i] +
            ", received string: " + returnedString);
            }
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

But when I run this client application ,I got the following exceptions.

---

```
"SEC5046: Audit: Authentication refused for [admin].
Web login failed: Login failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Failed file login for admin.
CORE5024: EJB module [JEENPT-SessionEJB1] unloaded successfully!
deployed with moduleid = JEENPT-SessionEJB1
**RemoteBusinessJndiName: jeenptbeans.NewSessionRemote; remoteBusIntf: jeenptbeans.NewSessionRemote
LDR5010: All ejb(s) of [JEENPT-SessionEJB1] loaded successfully!
ADM1006:Uploading the file to:[C:\Documents and Settings\Yamin\Local Settings\Temp\s1astempdomain1server1142715591\JEENPT-AppEJBClient1.jar]
Class [ jeenptbeans/NewSessionRemote ] not found. Error while loading [ class jeenptappejbclient1.Main ]
Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jeenptbeans/NewSessionRemote
deployed with moduleid = JEENPT-AppEJBClient1
Registering ad hoc servlet: WebPathPath: context root = "/JEENPT-AppEJBClient1", path = "'
Java Web Start services started for stand-alone app client com.sun.enterprise.appclient.jws.AppclientContentOrigin@1bb5013 registration name=JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, context root=/JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, module name=
CORE5024: EJB module [JEENPT-SessionEJB1] unloaded successfully!
deployed with moduleid = JEENPT-SessionEJB1
**RemoteBusinessJndiName: jeenptbeans.NewSessionRemote; remoteBusIntf: jeenptbeans.NewSessionRemote
LDR5010: All ejb(s) of [JEENPT-SessionEJB1] loaded successfully!
classLoader = WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
----------> Parent Classloader:
WebappClassLoader
  delegate: true
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
EJBClassLoader : 
urlSet = []
doneCalled = false 
 Parent -> java.net.URLClassLoader@103de90
SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@cf10ae
Java Web Start services ended for stand-alone app client com.sun.enterprise.appclient.jws.AppclientContentOrigin@1bb5013 registration name=JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, context root=/JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, module name=
ADM1064:The upload file at [C:\Documents and Settings\Yamin\Local Settings\Temp\s1astempdomain1server1142715591\JEENPT-AppEJBClient1.jar] exists and will be overwritten.
ADM1006:Uploading the file to:[C:\Documents and Settings\Yamin\Local Settings\Temp\s1astempdomain1server1142715591\JEENPT-AppEJBClient1.jar]
Class [ jeenptbeans/NewSessionRemote ] not found. Error while loading [ class jeenptappejbclient1.Main ]
Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jeenptbeans/NewSessionRemote
deployed with moduleid = JEENPT-AppEJBClient1
Registering ad hoc servlet: WebPathPath: context root = "/JEENPT-AppEJBClient1", path = "'
Java Web Start services started for stand-alone app client com.sun.enterprise.appclient.jws.AppclientContentOrigin@db05a8 registration name=JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, context root=/JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, module name=
CORE5024: EJB module [JEENPT-SessionEJB1] unloaded successfully!
classLoader = WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
----------> Parent Classloader:
WebappClassLoader
  delegate: true
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
EJBClassLoader : 
urlSet = []
doneCalled = false 
 Parent -> java.net.URLClassLoader@103de90
SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@cf10ae
Java Web Start services ended for stand-alone app client com.sun.enterprise.appclient.jws.AppclientContentOrigin@db05a8 registration name=JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, context root=/JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, module name=
ADM1064:The upload file at [C:\Documents and Settings\Yamin\Local Settings\Temp\s1astempdomain1server1142715591\JEENPT-AppEJBClient1.jar] exists and will be overwritten.
ADM1006:Uploading the file to:[C:\Documents and Settings\Yamin\Local Settings\Temp\s1astempdomain1server1142715591\JEENPT-AppEJBClient1.jar]
Class [ jeenptbeans/NewSessionRemote ] not found. Error while loading [ class jeenptappejbclient1.Main ]
Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jeenptbeans/NewSessionRemote
deployed with moduleid = JEENPT-AppEJBClient1
Registering ad hoc servlet: WebPathPath: context root = "/JEENPT-AppEJBClient1", path = "'
Java Web Start services started for stand-alone app client com.sun.enterprise.appclient.jws.AppclientContentOrigin@8500bc registration name=JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, context root=/JEENPT-AppEJBClient1, module name=
```

---

Please help me. Is this right or wrong making "Enterprise Application Client" application to test simple session bean? I also don't know where to add parameters for main function. To test this very simple ejb with netbean 6.7, please teach me the steps to follow. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

One area in which NetBeans is very good is [Documentation, Training & Support](http://netbeans.org/kb/index.html) (and [Community Docs](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CommunityDocs)). Here, I'd suggest to check [Creating EJB3 Sessions Beans using Netbeans 6.1 and Glassfish](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingEJB3UsingNetbeansAndGlassfish) (as written at the bottom of the page, *"Works with **NetBeans 6.0,6.5,6.1,6.7,6.7.1**"*).

Regarding the [Enterprise Application Client](http://blogs.oracle.com/pblaha/#enterprise_application_client_project_in) feature, it should be ok but I don't have any experience with it (I wonder how such a project works outside of NetBeans). I'd just use a standard Java client.

Comment: Indeed. But I wanted to point out where to look for good material (the first sentence).